# Terraform Decode function not converting JSON values to Terraform language values

Tags: json, terraform, hcl

If I'm understanding this correctly the jsondecode function in terraform should convert json values to terraform language values according to this: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsondecode

However in the use case I am trying this does not happen.
Here is the use-case that i'm using as a test:

```
Input:
   jsondecode("{\"hello\": \"null\"}")

Console output:
{
    "hello" = "null"
}

Desired Output/Expected Output:
    {
        "hello" = null
    }
```

Here the null value in string form in json isn't being converted to a terraform value after jsondecode is performed. My ultimate goal is using a json file to define my terraform variables to apply

Answer (score 1):

Your input JSON document has `"null"` written in quotes, which means that it's a JSON string containing the characters `null` rather than a JSON null value.

The correct way to write a null value in JSON is to just write the keyword `null` without any quotes, like this:

```
{"hello": null}
```

Escaping that for Terraform's quoted string syntax would give the following:

```
jsondecode("{\"hello\": null}")
```

This modified JSON document will produce the value you expected.